# how to get fields value from mysql function return

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some fields like `sat`, `sun`, `mon`, ...

the type of all of them is time.

I want to access the value inside of a field that this function is passing to me:

```
lower(substr(DAYname(now()),1,3))
```

i.e: if today is sunday, I want to get `sun` value.

is there any way to get fields value using functions return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE LOWER(SUBSTR(DAYNAME(NOW()),1,3))
  WHEN 'mon' THEN mon
  WHEN 'tue' THEN tue
  ...
  WHEN 'sun' THEN sun
  END as TodaysTime
FROM myTable
```

This is your best option because you can't use the string value as a column reference. By that I mean you *can* use the string value, but you'd have to write a procedure that uses dynamic SQL. I doubt it would be worth the trouble.

Comment: this is exactly what I need and I think there is no need to LOWER & SUBSTR

Comment: You're right: with this approach you can just do `CASE DAYNAME(NOW()) WHEN 'Monday' THEN mon WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN tue ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If i guessed correctly:

```
SELECT (SELECT lower(substr(DAYname(now()),1,3))) from Mytable
```